# Determine if CodeIgniter active record have set a WHERE-clause

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

Sooo! Well, the title should say most of it.
Are there any way to check if `$this->db-where('stuff', $data)` has been set previously?

I could go out and make a bunch of testing of my own code (flags ect...), but I would like to know if anyone has knowledge of some fast and easy way to do it!

Thanks in advance!

[EDIT - 24-Apr-14]
It's my own code. I have to variable that can be `null`, `String` or an `array`. They are `$categories` and `$budget`. So if budget is set to `100$` and category is set to `stuff` then I will need to use `db->or_where`, but if only one of them is set, I need only to use `db->where`. In this case it is quite simple just to check if first is set, but what if more values are used? I hope you get the point :)

Comment: I guess it's a bit confusing as to why you would need this functionality. Is there a reason you wouldn't know whether a where clause has been used? This may be more of a design issue than a functionality-of-framework issue.  Could you give an example as to how this would be used?

Comment: Are you working on someone else's code??

Comment: Please see the edit of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily determine whether a where clause is set or not. In CodeIgniter the Active Record class stores the wheres in an array called  `ar_where`. You can use this array to determine if any where clauses are set or not.

For example check the following code snippet :

```
$this->db->select()
            ->from("foo")
            ->where('bar',NULL);

        $this->db->or_where('xyz',NULL);

        print_r(sizeof($this->db->ar_where));
```

The following will output a value of `2`. So you can use this array to check for your result.